# How to invoke a New Dialog from EventActivity Handler or any handler other than OnMessageActivityAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, bots

I am trying to invoke a new Dialog on an event trigger in OnEventActivityAsync. I used DialogName (for eg EmployeeDetailsDialog Note: initialized in startup.cs. This is different from MainDialog which is instantiated with IBot implementation) and ran
`await EmployeeCardDialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);`

This works but breaks after the first waterfall step and will not continue until it comes from OnMessageActivityAsync. Now since OnMessageActivityAsync code has
`await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);` it will go to MainDialog again(Dialog=MainDialog). I was assuming that dialogs will continue till they are finished so in this scenario EmployeeCardDialog should finish and then MainDialog should be triggered. Am I doing it wrong?
( I don't want to get rid of MainDialog. I want to invoke another dialog while OnMessageActivityAsync has MainDialog Triggering.)
Thanks

DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {switch (turnContext.Activity.Name)
            {
                case "EmployeeSearchButton":
                        await EmployeeCardDialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
}   
}
```

DialogBot.cs

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

            await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);

        }
```

EmployeeCardDialog.cs

```
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                        IntroStepAsync,
                        EmployeeSearchStepAsync,
                        FinalStepAsync

            }));
```

As you can see I want to run the EmployeeCardDialog when say that event is passed from directline (on a button click). Now if I run this this first step IntroStepAsync runs and prompts and exits the dialog. The next input obviously being a message has to be routed through DialogBots.cs OnMessageActivityAsync which handles messages to the bot. Like the code says it will go to MainDialog and then do something else entirely. I was expecting a behaviour where when I run EmployeeCardDialog, this runs till completion and then continue what I am doing. Am I doing this wrong or that is the intended behaviour?

Comment: Could you please share related codes with MainDialog and EmployeeCardDialog?  It seems that you directly run the EmployeeCardDialog which caused the DialogState mixed.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Hope this edit helps. Let me know if that's not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I was able to resolve it by having a DialogSet singleton registered in startup and injecting this into my main bot class.

Inside the OnMessageAcitivtyAsync method I would call the CreateContextAsync method of the DialogSet to create a DialogContext. Once you have the DialogContext you can check if there is an active dialog if there is you can continue it, if not you can start a new dialog.

```
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DialogContext dialogContext = await Dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        if (dialogContext.ActiveDialog != null)
        {
            //Continue the current dialog
            await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
            return;
        }

        await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BaseDialog), null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Regards,

Comment: I was trying what you said was having issues. I added DialogSet to my startup. ``var
            ConversationState conv = new ConversationState(storage);
            IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> accessor = conv.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState");
            DialogSet Dialogset = new DialogSet(accessor);
            services.AddSingleton(Dialogset); ``
Does that look right? Somehow its not coming as an active Dialog when I check in OnMessageAcitivityAsync. I am invoking the Dialog in OnMembersAddedAsync like this :      ``empDialog.Run(turnContext, accessor, Dialogs)``

Comment: Another thing about what you said is if I change DialogExtensions Run method and inject the DialogSet there using DI would it not result in the same thing? Run Code: ``public static async Task Run()){var dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor); dialogSet.Add(dialog);
var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty) { await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);}}}``

Comment: For the time being, I have implemented something else where when this button is clicked i save a variable userClicked in memory and in MainDialog (Since this is the dialog that's invoked onMessage) i have a step that starts the employeeCardDialog(replaceDialogAsync) or skips if its not clicked. This works fine. If you were to do the same would you do what you suggested before or the solution I implemented is fine? Anyhow I would still like to know how to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Failed to continue dialog. A dialog with id EmployeeCardDialog could not be found." This is what I am getting latest. Cant seem to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks, I made it work. I did as you told I injected the DialogSet Singleton. I was having issues still and it was throwing Cant find dialog Id. I knew it had something to do with persistence of dialog state. I added a ``ConversationState.LoadAsync`` to update the with the saved stack and it works as intended. It only works after I update the conversationstate is this the right way? I am assuming it is. I want to be sure before closing this.

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't able to reply earlier. I'm not 100% sure if its the correct way but I would also assume it is.